# getting non matched values from two Datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, comparison

Is there any direct method for getting non matched values from two data table. I have one datatable which returns all the groups from Active Directory, and another datatable consist of all the group names from sharepoint list. But i need the non matched values by comparing these two datatables. please help me, if it possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want all of DataTable1 that not exist in DataTable2, all that are in DataTable2 that not exist in DataTable1 or both? What column(s) determines duplicates? What do you want as result, the `DataRow` or the key column(s)?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I want compare  DataTable1 that not exist in DataTable2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [DataRowComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907955.aspx) to compare the rows.

For instance, to compare the first rows of 2 data tables:

```
DataRow left = table1.Rows[0];
DataRow right = table2.Rows[0];

IEqualityComparer<DataRow> comparer = DataRowComparer.Default;
bool bEqual = comparer.Equals(left, right);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.Except` to do this. (Assuming an `ID` column)

```
IEnumerable<int> idsInDataTableA = dataTableA.AsEnumerable().Select(row => (int)row["ID"]);
IEnumerable<int> idsInDataTableB = dataTableB.AsEnumerable().Select(row => (int)row["ID"]);
IEnumerable<int> difference = idsInDataTableA.Except(idsInDataTableB );
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want compare DataTable1 that not exist in DataTable2

You can use Linq. Very efficient approaches are [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) or [`Enumerable.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.join.aspx)(as [LEFT OUTER JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx)) which are using sets:

```
var keyColRows = dt1.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => r.Field<int>("KeyColumn")
    .Except(dt2.AsEnumerable().Select(r2 => r2.Field<int>("KeyColumn"));

foreach(int inTable2Missing)
    Console.WriteLine(inTable2Missing);
```

or the `Join` approach selecting the whole `DataRow`:

```
var rowsOnlyInDT1 = from r1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                    join r2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                    on r1.Field<int>("KeyColumn") equals r2.Field<int>("KeyColumn") into groupJoin
                    from subRow in groupJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where subRow == null
                    select r1;
```

Here you can use `rowsOnlyInDT1.CopyToDataTable` to create a new `DataTable` of the rows in table1 which are unique/new or use `foreach` to enumerate them.